# Pandas - How to form groups then plot distribution (barplot) for each group based on two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, group-by

`----| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 (...)
row_1|   "A"   "Yes"   "Yes"
row_2|   "B"   "Yes"   "No"
row_3|   "A"   "Yes"   "Yes"
row_4|   "A"   "No"    "Yes"`

Result for "A":

`2        |
1        |              |
  ("Yes", "Yes")   ("No", "Yes")  ("Yes", "No")  ("No", "No")`

How do I group a pandas *DataFrame* in the above format by *col_1* and create a barplot for each group which visualises the distribution (number of occurrences) of value pairs *(col_2, col_3)*? *Col_2* and *col_3* have two distinct values which are *"Yes"* and *"No"*. The possible pairs would be *("Yes", "Yes")*, *("Yes", "No")*, *("No", "Yes")*, *("No", "No")*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BrianJoseph I edited my question. Thanks so far, I will try it out!

Comment: You're probably generating the axes but not displaying them. This is too much to demonstrate in a comment so I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['A', 'Yes', 'Yes'],
    ['B', 'Yes', 'No'],
    ['A', 'Yes', 'Yes'],
    ['A', 'No', 'Yes']],

    columns= ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']   
)

for key, grp in df.groupby(['col_2', 'col_3']):
    grp['col_1'].hist()
    plt.show()
```

You should see 3 plots -one for each col_2/col_3 pairing